# How to group tests by Stories in overall thucydides report?

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver, jbehave, thucydides

[image: Thucydides screenshot]

How can I configure the report to make Tests be grouped by jbehave Stories in common test list? I see now way to customize reports, at least I don't find them in manuals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Story` and `@Feature` annotations, cf [thucydides getting started](https://github.com/thucydides-webtests/thucydides/wiki/Getting-Started)

Comment: unfortunately I'm using jBehave plugin where I don;t see the way to use Features